# NSMutableDictionary data not saving in file for wrong file directory

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I have two `UITextField`

1. email
2. password

These two field values are stored in a `NSMutableDictionary` call `userData`. Now i want to save these two field values in a file, so that the records keep there and i can restore this record to check user login correctly. Here i want to accomplish that, but not working.

My code :

```
-(void) saveRegistrationData
{
    userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                initWithObjects:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"123456", nil]
                forKeys:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"admin@gmail.com", nil]];

    [userData setObject:passwordTextField.text forKey:emailTextField.text];

    NSString   *savePath = [@"/MediaFiles/Documents/" stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
    [userData writeToFile: savePath atomically: YES];

    //[userData writeToFile:@"MediaFiles/Documents/" atomically:YES];

    for (id key in userData)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ is for %@", key, [userData objectForKey:key]);
    }
}
```

I think the `path` is not setting correctly. If any one similar with the solution, please share with me. Thanks in advanced. Have a good day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working for a few reasons.

1) You're writing to a folder in the root of the device's filesystem. Apple uses sandboxing to prevent this from happening as you could overwrite and modify any system files.

2) You're writing to a folder rather than a file. To write to a file, you need to specify a filename (and extension). i.e. `"/MediaFiles/Documents/dnt_lk_at_dis.plist"`

In order to fix these issues, you need to be firstly getting the path to the sandbox (documents directory) and then append the filepath.

```
NSString *docsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"secret.plist";
NSString *filePath = [docsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
```

Furthermore, I strongly suggest that you instead use the keychain for storing sensitive user information. Anybody with a jailbroken device, or anybody that has access to the file system will be able to extract the user's information if it is stored in plain-text. At the very least, please encrypt the password before writing it to disk.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanations. Actually i tried with other many options as you said, like `/MediaFiles/Documents/dnt_lk_at_dis.txt`, but neither of them working. Besides i see a couple of tutorials about it. How to use plist to store data in it. But, it looks like little bit complicated to me. If i use the `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains`, then after go to library where suppose i find the `secret.txt` file, to check that the data are actually saving there? Thanks for sharing the security issue, i will work on it.

Comment: @Tulon that path won't work because of the first issue I mentioned, the code I posted will work for certain. You can check to see if it's writing to disk by `NSLog(@"%@", filePath)` and going to the containing folder in Finder (having run the app on iOS Simulator)

Comment: Yes, you are great. it is working & i find the `secret.txt` tracking the `NSLog` directory. But here now i realize one thing that, In `NSMutableDictionary` the previous data are not saved like database. When ever i give input, my previous record is gone from the `secret.txt` and it replace with the latest one. That mean i can't use `NSMutableDictionary` as Database, isn't it?

Comment: @Tulon Thanks! I don't really understand what you mean? As soon as you write to the same filepath, the old data will of course be overridden. What are you aiming to achieve instead?

Comment: i was thinking, all entry value will save in the directory file one after another and i can pick up those data at the time of user login. But i think i have to stay with `sqlite` to do that. NSMUtableDictionary can't use like database. :(

Comment: @Tulon you want an array of `NSDictionary`s.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) saveRegistrationData
{
    userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];


    [userData setObject:passwordTextField.text forKey:@"password"];
    [userData setObject:emailTextField.text forKey:@"email"];


    // Alternative to the above:
       userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]
                initWithObjects:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:passwordTextField.text, emailTextField.text, nil]
                forKeys:[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"password", @"email" nil]];


    NSString   *savePath = [@"/MediaFiles/Documents/myDict.plist" stringByExpandingTildeInPath]; // write to a file, not a dictionary
    [userData writeToFile: savePath atomically: YES];

    for (id key in userData)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@ is for %@", key, [userData objectForKey:key]); // now you should see the result that you want to. 
    }

    // Alternative for the above - the lazy way of doing it: 
    NSLog (@"theDictionary: %@", userData);
}
```

Please forgive me any typos or so. I did not compile it for you :-)

Comment: I appreciate downvotes, especially when they come with some explaining comment. What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: yes, i agree with you. Wait for a second to make that down to up. :)